# Integrating $g(x) e^{f(x)} $

Tags: calculus, integration

The exact question is the following:

$$I = \int x \cdot e^{5x+2}\, dx$$

I used integration by parts with:

$u = x$
$du = 1 \, dx$

and:

$dw = e^{5x+2} dx$
$w = \frac{1}{5}e^{5x+2}$

Here is where I seem to be doing something wrong.  My final steps are as follows:

$$I = x \left(\frac{1}{5} e^{5x+2}\right) - \frac{1}{5} \int e^{5x+2} \, dx
= \frac{x}{5} e^{5x+2} - \frac{1}{25} e^{5x+2} + C$$

According to Wolfram, I am missing a $(5x - 1)$ multiplied by the answer I currently have.  Where did I go wrong? Wolfram decided to express the entire integral in terms of one variable, substituting $5x+2$ for say, $z$, and expressing all $x$'s in terms of $z$, before integrating by parts.  Why does it choose to do that/why would that be a suggested way of solving it?  What's wrong with the method I used, and more importantly, where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is good, for sure. Well done !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your work is fine!

I'm guessing that Wolfram factored out the term $\frac{1}{25}e^{5x+2}$ to get

$$\frac 1{25}e^{5x+2}( 5x -1) + C$$

Expand this and you'll get precisely what you arrived at!

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I will have to remember small things like this when checking my answers against something else.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!